# php - mysql avoid sql injections

Tags: php, mysql

I have many functions like

```
updateUser($id,$username,$email)
updateMusic($id, $music)
```

etc...

Is there a generic function to avoid SQL injections ?

I just want to avoid using mysql_real_escape_string for each parameter I have

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$email= mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$music= mysql_real_escape_string($music);
```

Comment: You could just put them in your function, instead of having to pass them into the params each time.

Comment: yes there is a generic function - mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use,

```
list($id,$music) = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array($id,$music))
```

but prepared statements rocks

Answer (score 3):

- ALWAYS use prepared statements
- Do NOT use `mysql` driver, use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 2):

You should use parameterization and let the database driver handle it for you, i.e. with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', $user, $password); 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name); 
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value); 

// insert one row 
$name = 'one'; 
$value = 1; 
$stmt->execute();
```

Code from  [Bobby-Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, but you can parse all your inputs ( eg. GET and POST ) at beggining of the script

Comment: "Parse" is too vague to be useful IMO.